# Message Dialog box won't display

Tags: java

I don't think there is a problem with the dialog box code, I think I have a problem with my zip variable. Initially I had it set as a double and was trying to use a switch for the surcharge calculation. I changed it to a string, then the switch wouldn't work, so I changed that to an if / else statement. The compiler isn't finding any errors, but now my final message dialog box doesn't display after inputting all other data. I've found other people asking about this assignment, but none that are required to use dialog boxes, which is where my issue is. Here is my code, all help is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; //Needed for JOptionPane

public class EZShippingCompany
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
 {

  String input;     //to hold the string input
  String zip = new String();  //to hold zip
  double weight;    //to hold weight
  double length;    //to hold length
  double width;     //to hold width
  double height;    //to hold height
  double dimensions;//to hold dimensions

  double shippingcost=0; //to hold shipping cost
  double surcharge=0; //to hold surcharge
  double additionalcharge=0; // to hold additional 2% 
  double totalshippingcost; // to hold total


  //get zip
  input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please enter your zip code");

  //get weight
  input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please enter the weight of your shipment");
  weight = Double.parseDouble(input);

  //get length
  input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please enter the length in inches of your shipment");
  length = Double.parseDouble(input);

  //get width
  input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please enter the width in inches of your shipment");
  width = Double.parseDouble(input);

  //get height
  input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please enter the height in inches of your shipment");
  height = Double.parseDouble(input);

  dimensions = length * width * height;

  //calculate shipping cost
  {if (weight <= 5)
     shippingcost = 12.00;

  else if (dimensions + weight >=5.1 && dimensions + weight <= 15)
     shippingcost = 14.00;

  else if (dimensions + weight >= 15 && dimensions + weight <= 34)
     shippingcost = 17.00;

  else if (dimensions + weight >= 34 && dimensions + weight <= 45)
     shippingcost = 21.00;

  else if (dimensions + weight >= 45 && dimensions + weight <= 60)
     shippingcost = 33.00;

  else if (dimensions + weight > 60)
     shippingcost = 105.00;  }


  //calculate surcharge
  int x = zip.charAt(0);

  if (x == 4)
     surcharge = (.05 * shippingcost);
  else if (x == 6)
     surcharge = (.09 * shippingcost);

  else
     surcharge = (.014 * shippingcost);

  totalshippingcost = shippingcost + surcharge + additionalcharge;

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Zip Code: " + zip +
                                      "\nDimensions: " + dimensions + " square inches" +
                                      "\nSurcharge: " + surcharge +
                                      "\nTotal Shipping Cost: $" + totalshippingcost);
  //End the program
  System.exit(0);
  }

}
```

Comment: This isn't `jquery` question.. This is `java` question...

Comment: `String zip = new String();` -> `int x = zip.charAt(0);` what number do you expect to be on index *0* of an empty string?